# Access Unix PAM Password rules from Java?

Tags: java, passwords

Is there a sensible way to get the *nix PAM rules from Java?

I'm writing an application that has to ensure that passwords adhere to an organizations PAM rules, and I have no idea how to get them in order to adhere to them.

Comment: Jpam could be of use for you : http://jpam.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

There are already some implementations bringing PAM to Java. For example:

- http://jpam.sourceforge.net/
- https://java.net/projects/libpam4j/

There are also some works around implementations of `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule` for PAM. For example:

- http://jaas-pam.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.bablokb.de/jaas/

You can also relatively easy write your own. In the end you just have to cross the Java-native boundary.

However I'm not sure whether it will solve your problem. Because what seems to be major point here is to check whether password conforms to the rules. I don't know how to do that with PAM. So it is not about doing it from Java but about knowing what to actually do.